# Cylindrical Shells problem (can't find region)

Tags: calculus

"Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the x-axis."

I have two equations : x= 2y^(2)-y^(3) and x= 0. I am supposed to rotate about x axis.
I'm stuck on what region I am looking at for rotation. I got x=0 being the y axis, and the other equation to look something like a sin(x) curve. The area rotate is not very intuitive for me.

Comment: Maybe with cylindrical shells you are accustomed to $y=f(x)$ rotate about $y$ axis. If it will make you feel more comfortable, rotate region bounded by $y=2x^2-x^3$ and the $y$-axis, about the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cylinders lie along the $x$ axis.  At a given $y$, the minimum $x$ is $0$ and the maximum is $2y^2-y^3$.  The upper plot in [this Alpha page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x=2y%5E2-y%5E3) shows it well (but note the axes are switched as  André Nicolas suggests).  You are rotating the region above the horizontal axis around the vertical axis.  This would give $\int_0^2 (2y^2-y^3) 2\pi y\;dy$ where the height of the shell is $x=2y^2-y^3$, the radius is $y$, and the thickness of the shell is $dy$.